# download php (flv ok, pdf ok, zip wrong)

Tags: php, header, download, zip

I have two big problems with downloading.

First problem: when I download something from my website, if I click somewhere else on my website it does not work with the same browser while I'm downloading. Only if I use another browser while downloading the other pages work fine.

Second problem: the code below (for downloading) works fine with .flv and .pdf files but does not work with .zip files. When I download a .zip file it is unreadable on my computer.

Do you know how to solve these problems?

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type: application/download');       
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Media.".$format);
header("Content-Description: Download GeniusDollars");
header("Content-Length: ".($size_mb*1024*1024));

ob_clean();
flush();

readfile($file);
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. The first problem looks like there is a limitation on the number of concurrent connection of a single user. This limitation can be circumvented by using multiple browsers. Perhaps have a look at the mod_limitipconn apache module or the Apache config for the multi-processing module (MPM). (I am assuming that you use Apache)
2. I am not quite sure what goes wrong. You might want to verify that the correct filesize is being parsed. The script below in general works for me:

> ```
> <?php
> $file = "original.pdf"
> $size = filesize($file);
> header('Content-type: application/pdf');
> header("Content-length: $size");
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
> readfile($file);
> ?>
> ```